# How to implement datapicker in angular with zoneddatetime?

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Datepicker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHrBx.png)

Hello dear community, I have a problem with data that I receive the data in zoneDateTime format in my frontend, I want to implement datepicker to search by range, but I don't know how to make datepicker recognize zoneDateTime .

At this moment the fields filter as shown in image 1 in that way they filter but I want datepicker .

This is the code I have from angular material
I'm using the range datepicker

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input  matStartDate placeholder="Fecha más reciente"  name="Fecha más antigua" [(ngModel)]="final_fecha"  >
        <input matEndDate placeholder="End date"  name="inicio_fecha "[(ngModel)]="inicio_fecha"  >
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker  #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide some mock data and append your post with your component.ts file?